# Using word mutual

Tags: word-usage

Trying to create sentence for potential business partner. Is it common to use word `mutual` in sentence below:

> Possible we can have mutual interests on both sides.

Answer (score 2):

The use of "mutual interests" sounds fine in this context.

As it stands, however, this is not exactly a grammatical sentence.

You could say:

> "**It is** possible we can have mutual interests on both sides."

or

> "Possib**ly**, we could have mutual interests on both sides."

In fact, "both sides" is already implied by the word "mutual", so it would also be OK to omit that expression:

> "It is possible we can have mutual interests."